# Unable to initialize video driver (Opencv3.0.0)

Tags: video, opencv3.0

I am trying to open .mpg video in OPencv3.0.0 in Ubuntu14.04 for my project.

```
ERROR  icvOpenAVI_XINE(): Unable to initialize video driver.
Cannot open video!
```

I have added snippet of code for reference.

```
VideoCapture cap("umcp.mpg");
if (!cap.isOpened()){
    std::cout << "Cannot open video!\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the package libxine2 by using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxine2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try
sudo apt-get install libxine1